# Call webservice works from IE, not from Chrome or Firefox

Tags: ajax, web-services, cors

I have a webservice in the same domain of my site. I have an ajax call to consult that webservice and works fine from IE but from Chrome and Firefox, I cannot make it work.

My ajax call is:

```
       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false
        data: xml,
        url: url,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
           //On sucess action
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           //On error action
        },
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
            "SOAPAction": soapAction,
            "Content-Length": xml.length + 1
        }
    });
```

But from chrome and firefox I receive:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mydomain:83/<webservice>/<webservice>.asmx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://mydomain' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

I add to the webconfig:

```
   <system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://mydomain"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://mydomain"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

But no luck. Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up to soon. In my particular case, this do the trick for Chrome and Firefox

```
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://mydomain" />
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, SOAPAction" />
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
```